# Qt: ERROR in Exposing C++ Class to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qproperty

I keep getting the same error when I run the application:

> **qrc:/main.qml:13: ReferenceError: _myClass is not defined**

Where is the bug?

Furthermore, if I want to connect signal myIntChanged to a slot, where should I place my connect? In main.cpp or in constructor MyClass?

**myclass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_PROPERTY(int myInt READ getMyInt WRITE setMyInt NOTIFY myIntChanged)
    int myInt;
    inline int getMyInt() { return myInt; }
    inline void setMyInt(int _value) { myInt = _value; }

private:
    void initVariables();

    QTimer *timer;

private slots:
    void editVariables();

signals:
    void myIntChanged();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject (parent)
{
    initVariables();

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(editVariables()));
    timer -> start(3000);
}

void MyClass::initVariables()
{
    myInt = 0;
}

void MyClass::editVariables()
{
    myInt = myInt + 1;

    qDebug() << "myclass.cpp: timeout: variables edited.";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();
    engine.rootContext() -> setContextProperty("_myClass", myClass);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Exposed C++ Class")

    Text {
        anchors.top: parent.top; anchors.topMargin: 30
        anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: 30
        text: _myClass.myInt
    }
}
```

Comment: have your tried to eliminate from _myclass to just myclass

Comment: @Frrank Tried, but nothing changed! Also, the qml Text displays always '0', which is the initial value, but it does NOT show any update, even if the timer clearly works! I used Qt 5.10.0, if this info may be useful

Comment: Instead of text: _myClass.myInt. just try text: myClass.myInt

Comment: @Frrank already tried, but it doesn't change nothing...

Comment: Whats the errors this time

Comment: @Frrank exactly the same: Reference error: myClass is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161804/discussion-between-frrank-and-elena).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because with the `load()` statement being loading the .qml file, when reading it and verifying if the variables exist, they realize that this object does not exist since it is passed to them through `setContextProperty()`, a possible solution is to pass the object to it before it loads the .qml:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_myClass", myClass);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

It is not updated because it has not been notified through the signals that you have declared, the correct thing to do is to emit a signal every time the property changes, you must modify some methods:

```
inline void setMyInt(int _value) {
    if(myInt == _value)
        return;
    myInt = _value;
    emit myIntChanged();
}
```

---

```
void MyClass::editVariables()
{
    setMyInt(getMyInt()+1);
    qDebug() << "myclass.cpp: timeout: variables edited.";
}
```

Comment: Yes! The error disappears this way!! But why the QML Text does not update at timer's timeout?? @eyllanesc

Comment: Perfect, thank you, your answer was really clear! :-) @eyllanesc